# plotting multiple attribute columns of shapefile in panel

Tags: r, ggplot2, terra, tidyterra

I have a GIS vector file containing multiple attribute columns, such as t1, t2, t3, up to t8. My objective is to create individual plots for each attribute column within a panel display. Despite my attempts using terra, ggplot, and tidyterra, I consistently encounter errors during the process. I am not able to loop over with column names. `aes fill` is not taking column names and considering it as a discrete variable.   Any assistance in resolving this challenge would be greatly appreciated.

```
grids = vect('5k_grid_scenarios.gpkg')

grids = grids %>% 
            select(t1:t8)

p = c()

for (i in names(grids)){

  plot = 
    grids %>% 
    autoplot(aes(fill = i))+
    scale_fill_whitebox_c(palette = "pi_y_g")
  p[[i]] =plot
  
}

ggarrange(p)
```

Comment: Try with `aes(fill = .data[[i]])` to refer to the column with name `I`. Additionally I would suggest to use `lapply` to create your list of plots, e.g. something like `p <- lapply(names(grids), \(i) { grids |> autoplot(aes(fill = .data[[i]])) + ... })`. For more help please provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

You may need to create a "long" version with `tidyr::pivot_longer()` and skip the use of `ggarrange`.

**tidyterra** does not provide a direct `pivot_longer()` method for Spatvector but you can convert the SpatVector to a tibble with a column with the geometry dat and regenerate the object after pivoting, see:

```r
library(terra)
#> terra 1.7.71
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyterra)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

# I am using here a file to mock your input
grids <- vect(system.file("extdata/cyl.gpkg", package = "tidyterra"))

# Create t1:t8
set.seed(1234)
for (i in 1:8) {
  df <- tibble(col = runif(nrow(grids)))
  names(df) <- paste0("t", i)
  grids <- bind_spat_cols(grids, df)
}

# Your starting point
grids <- grids %>%
  select(t1:t8)

# Keep the crs for regenerate
keep_crs <- crs(grids)

# Pivot via as_tibble() and regenerate with as_spatvector()
grids_long <- grids %>%
  # The tibble would have a `geometry` column with the geometry info
  as_tibble(geom = "wkt") %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = t1:t8) %>%
  # Regenerate from tibble to SpatVector, see the crs here
  as_spatvector(geom = "geometry", crs = keep_crs)


# Faceted plot with facet_wrap()
autoplot(grids_long, aes(fill = value)) +
  facet_wrap(~name, ncol = 2) +
  scale_fill_whitebox_c(palette = "pi_y_g")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2024-02-19 with [reprex v2.1.0](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>